# How do we get an hour, minute and second difference between two datetimes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, datetime, date

The `table` Task has columns as:

```
Task(TaskID, TaskName, CreatedDate)
```

And want to execute code block based on datetime difference as:

> IF Task CreatedDate has passed 15 Minute THEN
>
> > Execute block #01
>
> ELSE IF Task CreatedDate has not passed 15 Minute yet THEN
>
> > Execute block #02

I tested below query but it gives result as `61633440`

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreatedDate, 108), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS MinuteDiff
```

How could we achieve above in sql?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188751.aspx) returns the current datetime something like `2017-03-09 15:19:53.770`.

`CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreatedDate, 108)` returns a string with only time `15:19:53`.

The second parameter of [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) takes a datetime so your string is implicitly converted to a datetime. In lack of something better to use for a date SQL Server uses `1900-01-01` so your second parameter ends up to be `1900-01-01 15:19:53.000` and the function returns the number of minutes since the beginning of the previous century.

Remove the convert in the second parameter and it should work just fine for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sql code to calculate the number of minutes, seconds, hours that have passed since the CreatedDate:

```
select datediff(second, CreatedDate, getdate())
select datediff(minute, CreatedDate, getdate())
select datediff(hour, CreatedDate, getdate())
```

Executing two different code blocks will likely require you to do record by record processing which is time consuming and resource expensive.

If you were merely wishing to report or manipulate the data, you could write two queries.

```
   Update TableX
      set ColumnY = 'Value'
   where datediff(minute, CreatedDate, getdate()) >= 15

   Update TableX
      set ColumnY = 'DifferentValue'
   where datediff(minute, CreatedDate, getdate()) < 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Difference between two datetime to get result in hours:minutes:second formate

```
declare @Date1 datetime
declare @Date2 datetime

set @Date1 = '2019-01-25 00:00:00.000'
set @Date2 = '2019-01-24 17:14:05.000'

SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Date1 - @Date2, 108), 8) AS ResultTime
```

Answer

06:45:55

Comment: While this may be a nice solution in some cases, it's worth keeping in mind that you will only get a valid result if the actual difference between the two datetime values is less than 24 hours. Also, it's not very obvious how you would use the result in a scenario similar to the OP's . The purpose of getting the time difference in the OP's case is so that it can be compared to a certain value (15 minutes). Perhaps you could show in your answer how you would compare the result to a given value (say, 15 minutes, as in the question). That would make your answer more relevant to the question.